# Detecting Chrome using .net 3.5 and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Okey,  I am using this code to detect the browser

```
<%= Request.Browser.Browser %>
```

When using chrome, it is giving me browser

AppleMAC-Safari

I need it to say chrome, Ater looking around, i found this

[Google Chrome/Safari Same Browser Name and Version !](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633843/google-chrome-safari-same-browser-name-and-version)

I did all that was given in the answer to the question, but that doesn't help.

I am using VS 2010 and using .net framework 3.5

thankyou.

Edit: I tried doing what is suggested on this page

http://www.codemonkeez.com/2010/06/detect-google-chrome-browser-with.html

it is still giving me

AppleMAC-Safari

:/

thanks again.

Comment: Your question's title says .Net 2.0, and the last line says 3.5. And your tag says 3.0. Please edit your question and make all 3 match.

Comment: it was a mistake .. its .net 3.5 .. thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
if (Request.UserAgent.Contains("Chrome") && !Request.UserAgent.Contains("Edge"))
{
    //do chrome stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `<%= Request.UserAgent %>` which will give you something like this:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/534.24 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/11.0.696.68 Safari/534.24
```

Comment: i need to do differnt stuff for chrome and safari each, so detecting the browser is the key for me.

Comment: I am using .NET 4 and when I do Request.Browser.Browser I do get the result as Chrome

Answer (score 1):

Note that Chrome didn't exist back in 2005, when Visual Studio 2005 was released.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<div>
Your browser is: <%=Request.Browser.Browser %>
</div>
```